# How do I generate css to reverse css statements from a linked css file?

Tags: css

Here's the offending css:

```
ul.pricing-table span {
    display:block;
    font-size:40px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#222;
    padding:30px 0;
    line-height:1.3;
}
```

I attemped to fix it with:

```
<style>
.spans {
    display:inline;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding: 0 0;
    line-height:1;
}
</style>
```

Where the span looks like:

```
<p>This is more of a test <span class="spans" style="color: #e03e2d;">do red</span> and <span class="spans" style="color: #34495e;">do black</span></p>
```

No matter where I put the style block, before the link or after it still uses the style from the file.  I thought that what I put in style blocks in the html overrode linked files.  Obviously not.

I also tried various schemes of "initial" "revert" "set"  none of which had any effect and most gave me errors.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't provide the full HTML code, the issue isn't reproducible, so we need to make some assumptions. 
 
 It's not about where you put your style block, what matters is selector specifity. 
 When you select element with `ul.pricing-table span` selector, you select the `<span>` within the `<ul>` with `pricing-table` class. When you use `.spans` you select any element with class `.spans`, so the latter has lower specifity. 
 Try something like `ul.pricing-table span.spans` instead of `.spans` and read this to deeper understand the point [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#:~:text=Specificity%20is%20the%20means%20by,different%20sorts%20of%20CSS%20selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#:%7E:text=Specificity%20is%20the%20means%20by,different%20sorts%20of%20CSS%20selectors) 
 To quickly compare selector specifity you may want to use something like this https://specificity.keegan.st/

```css
ul.pricing-table span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #222;
  padding: 30px 0;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

ul.pricing-table span.spans {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 0 0;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pricing-table">
  <li>
    <p>This is more of a test <span class="spans" style="color: #e03e2d;">do red</span> and <span class="spans" style="color: #34495e;">do black</span></p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) issue. Your selector (`.spans`) is composed of one class when the selector from the file (`ul.pricing-table span`) is composed of one class plus 2 elements. Unless you use `!important` which you shouldn't, where ever you put your CSS the "stronger" selector will always prevail. As an example you could change your selector to `p > span.spans`